# Changing php-fpm values in the local php .user.ini

Tags: php, linux

In my /etc/php-fpm.d/www.someweb.com.conf, I have the following configuration:

```
php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir] = /home/www.someweb.com/tmp
```

Is there a way to change these value in my local .user.ini?

Kind of:

```
upload_tmp_dir = "/home/www.someweb.com/tmp"
```

Comment: I see. Thank u.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php
Any value that has `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` in the `Changeable` column cannot be altered by anything other than the master php.ini file. This is for server security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not change values which are not changeable, e.g Named: PHP_INI_SYSTEM. - See official documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php